# Can I get a property from a collection using Linq in a more elegant way than this?

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I have a collection of items

```
List<Thing> MyListOfThings
```

I get this list from a db using PetaPoco like this

```
var MyListOfThings = db.Fetch<Thing>();
```

Then I want to get the value of a property like this:

```
otherObject.Value = MyListOfThings.SingleOrDefault(q => q.UniqueID == otherValue).SomeProperty;
```

I think this is a very elegant solution, the problem is if the collection does not contain an object with the `UniqueID` of `otherValue`. Then it goes BANG with a null reference exception.

The solution I have been using is

```
otherObject.Value = MyListOfThings.SingleOrDefault(q => q.UniqueID == otherValue) == null
  ? ""
  : MyListOfThings.SingleOrDefault(q => q.UniqueID == otherValue).SomeProperty;
```

This works, Resharper still complains that there is a possible NullReferenceException, but I guess that's just because it doesn't count the first line as a nullcheck.

However... this looks ugly and is so unDRY that it's dripping...

Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `SomeProperty` is a `string`, and you want `string.Empty` as a fallback value. If that's right, then you can do

```
otherObject.Value = 
    (from thing in MyListOfThings
    where thing.UniqueID == otherValue
    select thing.SomeProperty)
        .SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

The LINQ expression is an `IEnumerable<string>` containing the `SomeProperty` value of all `Thing`s having the relevant `UniqueID`; this might be an empty enumerable.

Comment: Even though I prefer the method-chaining way, you get this. But I'm not quite sure that it's any more elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a where statement first and use DefaultIfEmpty to set your fallback value

```
otherObject.Value = MyListOfThings
    .Where(q => q.UniqueID == otherValue)
    .Select(q => q.SomeProperty)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
MyListOfThings object = MyListOfThings.where(q => q.UniqueID == otherValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will either get an object of my thing or null

```
if(!object.IsNull) // null check so wont Bang
{
//assign value here
}
```

Comment: `Where(condition).FirstOrDefault()` returns the same as `FirstOrDefault(condition)` but might be less efficient.

Comment: ``MyListOfThings`` is always unique on ``UniqueID``, that would make the ``SingleOrDefault`` the correct method to use here. But still, this isn't a more elegant solution than the one I'm currently using.